# Checking user input with scanner

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner

I am trying to implement a simulator that has certain commands the user can input.
One of these commands is "s" which when entered should step through one instruction of the assembly file. However there is another instruction with the format "s num" where the user can define just how many instructions they want to step through.

I check for this

```
    if(input.equals("s"))
    {
        //check for num next
        if(user.hasNextInt())
        {
            input = user.next();
            step(Integer.parseInt(input), assembler);
        }
        else
        {
            step(1, assembler);
        }
    }
```

However the problem is if the user only enters "s" the scanner will wait for the next input rather than just calling step. My idea is if there is an int after the s was input then proceed with the num step, other wise just call step.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: How does the scanner know that you finished typing? I think it waiting for you to press return or enter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would split the input into two parts and then treat it. For example,

```
String input = user.nextLine();
String array[] = input.split(" ");
if(array.length<2){
    //check for `s`
}else{
    //check for `s num`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try this:

```
if(input.equals("s"))
{            
    step(1, assembler);
}
else if(input.startsWith("s") && input.length() > 2)
{
    step(Integer.parseInt(input.substring(input.indexOf(" ")+1)), assembler);
}
```

If control were to go inside the `else if` block, the current solution assumes that there is always a number after the String `s` with a white space delimiter in between them, but you can go on further and do more validations if necessary.